# When i call notifyItemRemoved on recyclerView i get an abstractMethodError

Tags: android

Below is my error

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.animatePersistence(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder, 
    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator$ItemHolderInfo, 
    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator$ItemHolderInfo)"
```

Comment: More details! Post your code.

Comment: Please post details on your problem. thanks

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow, please follow the tips in the tour to ask good questions (http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You need to give more details, otherwise it's not possible for us to help you !! Merry X-mas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call this method to remove a item from recyclerView

```
   public void removeAt(int position, int listSize) {
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, listSize);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, What is the root of this issue ?, I have same issue but error when insert data

Comment: you cannot invoke a function in an argument so instead of list.size() use list.size